# I have a huge bounty and the guards won't arrest me. Why?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I killed someone as part of a quest in Gorhart. He wasn't an enemy per se (I sided with bandits on this one) so I incurred a bounty after I killed him. Here's what my current stats look like:

[image]

As you can see, my bounty is currently 5,292 because I assaulted and murdered an innocent. To my surprised, when I walked outside, directly after the murder, none of the guards seemed to care. No one rushed to arrest me. I even tried to talk to them to see if that would trigger something and that didn't work. Why aren't the guards doing anything?

Comment: I *think* it's because Gorhart is so small, and has no jail.

Comment: I don't think so. I got arrested for stealing earlier and there were two options: jail or fine. I paid the fine to avoid jail. They are pretending like I didn't even do anything. :/

Comment: I think that building slightly east of other buildings in Gorhart is the jail. Also, I can't +1 this question until it gets freehand circles!

Comment: @Sterno One terribly drawn freehand circle in exchange for one upvote :p

Comment: Was it Brother Delf? I noticed you can't kill him without getting Murder added to your rap sheet, however if you do it without people seeing you then nobody comes after you

Comment: @Rachel Yes. it was Brother Delf. Do you know why I still get murder added even if no one sees me? It's weird to have a giant bounty but have no one come after you...

Comment: @spugsley I have no idea. My boyfriend saved/loaded the game quite a few times because he didn't want the bounty on his head, and killed Delf many ways (he's an assassian), but he always got the bounty. I just figured it was one of the many unpolished quirks of the game which aren't enough to detract from the game.

Comment: @Rachel true enough but I also don't want to run around with a bounty so that quest will have to stay open until (if it ever)gets patched :(

Answer (score 3):

I don't really think bounty really matters and paying fines or going to jail is pointless, it wont cause you many problems just to run away or keep killing guards and civilians.  My current bounty is at 4 million and the only problems I face are when I try to re-enter a city that I recently killed a bunch of people in like the past hour or so, but the agro in the city fades away.

Answer (score 1):

No one else was in the building when I murdered him, which I assume was probably the case for you as well. Therefore, no one called the guards.

If you wish to be arrested and pay off your bounty, simply steal something in plain sight.

Otherwise, what happened to you is functionally identical to you choosing to resist arrest, and then dodging/blinking/running out of town - a trivially easy task so far in my experience. A town and its guards will always "de-aggro" to you eventually anyways.